# Java character input validation

Tags: java, validation

I want to validate a single character in a java application.
I don't want the user to be able to enter a character outside the range `[a - p]` (ignoring uppercase or lowercase) or `numbers`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Choose letter in range [a - p]");
letter = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Improved question grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [**regex**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to filter input

```
.matches("^[a-pA-P0-9]*$") //this will not allow outside range of [a-p A-P] or numbers
```

`^`  Assert position at start of the string

`-`  Create a character range with the adjascent tokens

`a-p`  A single character in the range between `a` and `p` (*case sensitive*)

`A-P`  A single character in the range between `A` and `P` (*case sensitive*)

`0-9`  A single character in the range between 0 and 9

`*`  Repeat previous token `zero` to `infinite` times, as many times as possible

`$`  Assert position at end of the string

like this:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Choose letter in range [a - p]");
    letter = input.next().charAt(0);

    if (Character.toString(letter).matches("^[a-pA-P0-9]*$")) {
         System.out.println("valid input");
    }else{
         System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
```

[**SEE REGEX DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/bZ5lT3/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can encapsulate it with a while loop to check if the letter is in the range or not and just keep asking the user to input a letter

```
do {
    System.out.print("Choose letter in range [a - p]"); letter = input.next().charAt(0);
} while (letter is not in range of [a-p]); // pseudo code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with regex, simple checks on the input can take care of it.

```
        System.out.print("Choose letter in range [a - p]");
        String letter = input.nextLine();
        if (letter.length() == 1 && ('a' <= letter.charAt(0) && letter.charAt(0) <= 'p')) {
            System.out.println(letter);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
```

I'm using nextLine() in the event that multiple characters are accidentally entered, which is why I check that the length of letter == 1 and that the letter falls in the range that I want, otherwise it is invalid input.